# Modal not hiding with JS, jQuery nor CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show a modal on mobile only.

Even though I am quite sure my JS is correct, it is not working

Could anyone please take a look?

```
<div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto aboutMid aboutMid1">
                            <figure class="cap-left">

                                <img src="http://www.classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/house.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><figcaption>
                                    The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
                                    </figcaption></a>
                            </figure>

                        </div>


                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#myModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Here is a Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Here goes the content of the modal.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JS

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#myInput').focus()
    })  

$("img").click(function() {
  if ($(window).clientWidth() < 768) {
    $('.modal-body').html($('figcaption').text());
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Presently I don't have any css affecting it

Thanks

Comment: `768px` maybe on the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want would be to use native Bootstrap 4 classes.

For example, the `d-block` class would display the modal (d stands for display). And when you add the `d-sm-none` class additionally to that, it would NOT display the modal on devices that `sm` (small) or larger.

Of course, the `sm` breakpoint is the 768px breakpoint in Bootstrap 4.

So, if you add the `d-block d-sm-none` classes to your modal, you should get the effect you want even without using JavaScript.

To fix the issue with the dimmed background you apply the same trick (in reverse) to the figcaption like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto aboutMid aboutMid1">
    <figure class="cap-left">

        <img src="http://www.classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/house.png" class="img-fluid">
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="d-inline d-md-none"><figcaption>
            The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
            </figcaption></a>
        <figcaption class="d-none d-md-inline">
            The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
        </figcaption>
    </figure>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#myModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Here is a Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Here goes the content of the modal.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

That makes the linked caption disappear on 768px screens and above and makes the unlinked caption appear from 768px onwards.

Comment: Ok, that works, but it greys out my screen because there is no modal. Do you know how I can prevent it? Actually that doesn't work on mobile with d-block, so had to remove it. Only problem is the greyed out on desktop

Comment: Check out my updated answer + code snippet. That fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry, was afk. Going to check that

Comment: I can't have class="d-inline d-sm-none" on the anchor otherwise my caption won't appear on desktop

Comment: Please test my entire snippet and you'll see that it will, in fact, appear on the desktop.

Comment: I am sorry, it does. my problem now lies with tablet view. I tried changing to -md but nothing... any ideas on that? thanks

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you are trying to achieve for the tablet view?

Comment: Same as mobile, since the caption inside the figure on tablet view is small

Comment: OK, check my updated code snippet. I just changed **both** of class instances from `-sm-` to `-md-`.

Comment: going to test on my tablet one sec ;). Yeah, I tried -md as well (I copied your sniped just in case) and nothing. Should I do -lg instead?

Comment: Using dev tools in browser you can test all screens sizes instantly.

Comment: edited my answer, previous to this :). should i go for -lg?

Comment: "Should I do -lg instead" -- it really depends on what effect you want.

Comment: used -lg and it works on tablet portrait but not landscape :(. -md didn't work. One last question: How can I make the Modal to show my caption? Do I have to write it all over again, or is there a way to capture it?

Comment: Well, `lg` really just means screens at least 992px wide. Regarding your other question: Please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it and then post your second question as a separate question so that I can earn a few points. :-)

Comment: of course... before that, is there a way to be more specific  for tablets? on my iPad2 landscape its not working :/

Comment: No, Bootstrap is not targeting devices (because there are too many different ones). It is only ever targeting the screen size. Targeting specific devices is nearly impossible in real life. So, nobody does it.

Comment: I see, thanks. So I should just leave it? :/ thanks. I will post here the link regarding the new question

Comment: So, the reason why it doesn't seem to work in landscape on your iPad is simply because it's wider than 992px in landscape mode.

Comment: Oh, yes, you could set custom breakpoints, of course. But I wouldn't really advise doing that. But you could.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382877/make-modal-capture-figcaption   this is the new post

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at it? :)

Comment: Looking at it now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only small devices you want it displayed on, you can use Bootstrap's `hidden-md-up` or `hidden-sm-up`. This means that devices `> 768px` will not display the modal.

```
<div class="hidden-md-up">
 //content
</div>
```

Check out Bootstrap's [Responsive utitlities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/). Very handy for project's that require responsiveness.

Comment: the problem with that is that it doesn't work on tablets (even tried -mg and -lg) and it greys out on desktop :/

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? The functionality or Bootstrap displaying the modal?