# Make Modal capture figcaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

so I have this code for a fig caption and a modal to show up on mobile and tablets, but I would like to make the modal open my caption instead of writing the caption again inside the modal.

I have many images with captions, so this with be optimal

How is this possible?

Thanks

```
<div class="col-5 col-sm-2 ml-auto aboutMid aboutMid1">
                            <figure class="cap-left">

                                <img src="http://www.classichits.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/house.png" class="img-fluid">
                                <a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="d-inline d-lg-none"><figcaption>
                                    The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
                                    </figcaption></a>
                                <figcaption class="d-none d-lg-inline">
                                    The house is a converted farm building featuring traditional wooden shutters and terracotta toof tiles
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>

                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#myModal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Here is a Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Here goes the content of the modal.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-5 col-sm-2 mr-auto mr-sm-0 aboutMid aboutMid1">
                            <figure class="cap-left">
                                <img src="assets/about/about2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                <figcaption>
                                    The large garden features breathtaking views of the valley and Puilaurens Castle                                 </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I need js to make the modal use figcaption?

Comment: oh sorry... done :)

Comment: So, instead of showing captions on small screens, you want to show the caption in a modal when the user clicks/taps on the image. Is that what you want?

Comment: correct... and make sure it displays the caption I have, inside the modal

Comment: Normally, the modal displays the content you put inside i.e. it's normally static. If you want to dynamically grab the figcaption content and put it into the modal, then you're gonna need to use JavaScript/jQuery. Add the jquery tag to your question to get attention from jQuery folks.

Comment: not your domain? :P

Comment: I'm currently trying to focus on Bootstrap 4 questions only.